# Java8-Stream: no instance(s) of type variable(s)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a json as below:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "partners": [
            {
                "configuration": {
                    "connect-fleet-sync": false
                },
                "id": "cf89cbc5-0886-48cc-81e7-ca6123bc4857"
            },
            {
                "configuration": {
                    "connect-fleet-sync": false
                },
                "id": "cf89cbc5-0886-48cc-81e7-ca6123bc4967"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "partners": [
            {
                "configuration": {
                    "connect-fleet-sync": false
                },
                "id": "c3354af5-16e3-4713-b1f5-a5369c0b13d6"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need a method which i receive the id and it gives me **ids of partners**.

Fr example `getPartnersOfClient(2)` and then i expect it returns:

```
["cf89cbc5-0886-48cc-81e7-ca6123bc4857","cf89cbc5-0886-48cc-81e7-ca6123bc4857"]
```

Here is what i have tried:

```
  public List<String> getPartnersOfClient(String clientId, MyClient[] allMyClients) {

    Stream<String> myClient =
        Stream.of(allMyClients)
            .filter(client -> client.getId() == Integer.valueOf(clientId))
            .map(MyClient::getPartners)
            .map(Partner::getPartnerId)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return allPartners;
  }
```

But, in the line `.map(Partner::getPartnerId)` it complains with:

```
reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Partner[] conforms to Partner
```

Here is the picture of error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `getPartners()` returns a `Partner[]`, not a `Partner`, so you can't apply `Partner::getPartnerId` on these arrays.

You can use `flatMap` to get a `Stream<Partner>` of all the individual `Partner` instances.

```
Stream<String> fdeClient =
    Stream.of(allFdeClients)
        .filter(client -> client.getId() == Integer.parseInt(clientId))
        .flatMap(f -> Stream.of(f.getPartners()))
        .map(Partner::getPartnerId)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: More idiomatic would be `Arrays.stream(f.getPartners())`. As a side note, `client.getId() == Integer.valueOf(clientId)` rings the alarm bells. It works if `getId()` returns a primitive type, but will perform a reference comparison if it returns, e.g. `Integer`. It’s better to use `Integer.parse(clientId)` instead of `Integer.valueOf(clientId)`, to force a primitive `int` value on the right-hand side.

Comment: Actually, it returns an empty list.
I just upvoted the answer because it fixed the error, but the question is still open.

Comment: @Jeff it might be due to the comparison Holger mentioned. Try to use `parseInt` instead of `valueOf`. Or use `equals` instead of `==` if you are comparing two Integers.